# Provisioning profile not showing up in organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode-organizer

Provisioning profiles is not showing up in library. Can someone help me out with this? I am in the process of submitting my app to apple.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If ypu are using Xcode 5, then profiles can be accessed through Preferences/Accounts

Comment: Preferences/Accounts/Apple IDs/View Details...